# in arduino how to print character for givien ascii number?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am using Arduino Uno. Basically I am reading a number(ASCII number) from the serial.Read() and storing the value in a variable of type int (4 byte).
I want to print the character assigned for that ASCII number to the Serial Monitor. 
For example consider given number is 97. I want to see  'a' printed in the Serial Monitor.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is [`Serial.write()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write)

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {} // Wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB.
  byte ASCIIvalue = 97;
  Serial.print("The ASCII encoding for the value ");
  Serial.print(ASCIIvalue);
  Serial.print(" is: ");
  Serial.write(ASCIIvalue);
}

void loop() {}
```

Output:

```
The ASCII encoding for the value 97 is: a
```

Comment: what's the difference between "serial.print" and "serial.write" ?and thanks for your reply